# Hierarchy in REST API

Tags: database, rest, api, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
Work Experience (like SomeCompany.com)
└─Roles (like Project Manager)
  └─Projects
```

So user can add his `Work Experience`. To that he can add `roles` with specific `projects`.

I would like to GET `projects` for the user `id 1`, but there is only relation between projects & roles. 
Do I really need to make like 4 requests to get Projects?

1. Get User
2. Get Work Experiences
3. Get Roles
4. Get Projects

So if I have more roles for different work experiences, I would have to make 20 requests just to get my projects. Isn't it not efficient? I would have to load some unnecessary data...

Is it possible to create just endpoint:
`/projects` and filter it by user id ?

How it should be managed on API? For me, as frontend dev it looks quite not efficient, especially when people use mostly mobiles, so requests like this will kill your battery pretty quick.

How do you guys handle relations like this?

Thank you!

Comment: whats stopping you to get all data for a user and filter out what is required to be displayed on the screen..  If that has a challenge with the size of data and this is a specific endpoint you would need, you may design it as  GET :
 <host>:<port>/<context>/user/{uid}/we/role/project

Comment: I am working on the frontend side of the project, and our backend guys came up with solution I mentioned above. The think you proposed would be ideal in my world. They are saying that there is to much circulations...

Comment: if you think that was fine, you can approve it as correct answer.. thanks

Comment: @crotoan What do they mean by "circulations"?

Comment: Not sure.. I am sure that above is the not the real use case.. may be the real use case have nested objects or some thing like we->role->project->{we->role->project->{..}}.. and so on.. Other than that, it's only a matter of having multiple loops.. for that i don't think a backend developer will ever complaint.. :)

Comment: @alex, sorry. I meant nesting.

Comment: "Is it possible to create just endpoint: /projects and filter it by user id ?" - yeah, just do that, like this `/projects?userid=123`

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources) is mildly relevant.

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872501/restful-flat-hierarchy-vs-dynamic-hierarchy-for-search-resource

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067968/rest-resource-path-design

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259843/how-to-structure-rest-resource-hierarchy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104578/rest-complex-composite-nested-resources

Comment: See [What are best practices for REST nested resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources)

Answer (score 0):

whats stopping you to get all data for a user and filter out what is required to be displayed on the screen..

If that has a challenge with the size of data and this is a specific endpoint you would need, you may design it as 
`GET : <host>:<port>/<context>/user/{uid}/we/role/project`

Answer (score 0):

Your API's entities shouldn't bee too tightly coupled. If you need to get eg. all projects for a user, there should be a `user_id` in your `projects` table for example, then go for eg. `/users/<user_id>/projects`.

If projects would be standalone and listable, a `/projects` would only list the `projects` (paginated etc).

Personally, I tend to follow the RESTful API approach and I've found it's really helpful. [This page](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html#) and [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_introduction.htm) might help you understand how to better organise your RESTful API